# Calling Face API from Microsoft Computer Vision with request body is "application/json"

Tags: c#, api, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to call the Face API from Microsoft website and I found the sample code on their site. In their code, they use the `"Detect API"` as an example, but I want to test the `"Create Face List"` API. I figure it out that I need to change the "Content type" from "application/octet-stream" to "application/json" and fill the "Json field". Unfortunately, I'm new in calling API aspect.

Hope you guys can help with this.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/csharp#feedback) is the link of sample code.

And [here](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039524b/console) is the link of "Create Face List" API.

```
using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
    // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
    // The other content types you can use are "application/json"
    // and "multipart/form-data".
    content.Headers.ContentType =
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    // Execute the REST API call.
    response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

    // Get the JSON response.
    string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Display the JSON response.
    Console.WriteLine("\nResponse:\n");
    Console.WriteLine(JsonPrettyPrint(contentString));
    Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to exit...");
}
```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, still not get used to this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't know how to post the code. I need to take some time, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039524b), I see that for the ws "Create a FaceList" you have to call a `Http Put` method, with content type `application/json`.

Here the description of this service:

> FaceList - Create
>   Create an empty face list with user-specified faceListId, name and an optional userData. Up to 64 face lists are allowed in one subscription. 
>   Face list is a list of faces, up to 1,000 faces, and used by Face - Find Similar. 
>   After creation, user should use FaceList - Add Face to import the faces. Faces are stored on server until FaceList - Delete is called. 
>   Find Similar is used for scenario like finding celebrity-like faces, similar face filtering, or as a light way face identification. But if the actual use is to identify person, please use PersonGroup / LargePersonGroup and Face - Identify. 
>   Please consider LargeFaceList when the face number is large. It can support up to 1,000,000 faces.

Http Method
PUT

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

// Request headers
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");

var uri = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/facelists/{faceListId}?" + queryString;

HttpResponseMessage response;

// Request body
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"name\": \"sample_list\",\"userData\": \"User-provided data attached to the face list.\"}");

using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);
    // Get the JSON response.
    string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Display the JSON response.
    Console.WriteLine("\nResponse:\n");
    Console.WriteLine(JsonPrettyPrint(contentString));
    Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to exit...");
}
```

Currently, the location base urls are those:

- West US - westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- West US 2 - westus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- East US - eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- East US 2 - eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- West Central US - westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- South Central US - southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- West Europe - westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- North Europe - northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- Southeast Asia - southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- East Asia - eastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- Australia East - australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- Brazil South - brazilsouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- Canada Central - canadacentral.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- Central India - centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- UK South - uksouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- Japan East - japaneast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- Central US - centralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- France Central - francecentral.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- Korea Central - koreacentral.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- Japan West - japanwest.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- North Central US - northcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com

**Request parameters**

`faceListId`: Valid character is letter in lower case or digit or '-' or '_', maximum length is 64.

**Request headers**

*`Content-Type`* (optional): Media type of the body sent to the API.

*`Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`*: Subscription key which provides access to this API. Found in your Cognitive Services accounts.

**Request body**

JSON fields in request `body`:

```
{
    "name": "sample_list",//Name of the created face list, maximum length is 128.
    "userData": "User-provided data attached to the face list." //Optional user defined data for the face list. Length should not exceed 16KB.
}
```

I hope that may help you

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate for your help, but can you pass me a format of the body for the line 

byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{body}");

I'm getting stuck at the part.

Comment: @phutran you can find all the specification in the link of the documentation, I'll update my answer with also that specs.

Comment: This is my code for the request body:       
 byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("name:sample_list,userData:10KB}");

Comment: there are some error in your code, you have to write like this: byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"name\": \"sample_list\",\"userData\": \"10KB\"}");

Comment: Thank you for you update, about the Request Body, can you take an example in your code?

Comment: Woa, I did it, thank you so much nmbrphi. You just save my life.

Comment: You'll save a fair bit of effort by using the pre-built client SDK: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face.  It will handle all serialization/deserialization for you.